# Create a sticky expander in a listbox wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, wpf-listview

Currently I have a listbox and expander as listboxitemtemplate. At a time user can select only one item and the expanders will expand if selected. Now i have to add a scrollviewer and during the scroll the expander header should stay sticky to the listbox even when the selected listboxitem is out of current view. In HTML we can achieve this with setting header div with sticky and content as relative.

The sample code to try this is here

```
<ScrollViewer>
        <ListBox Grid.Row="1" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                <Expander Header="head1" Content="content1" IsExpanded="True"/>
                <Expander Header="head2" Content="content2"/>
                <Expander Header="head3" Content="content3"/>
                <Expander Header="head4" Content="content4"/>
        </ListBox>
</ScrollViewer>
```

I have tried ListBox.scrollintoview() but it locks the scroll after selected item. I also tried with dockpanel and docking it to the top. But it didn't produce the result as expected. Kindly help with any suggestions or code.

Comment: one way would be to turn the selectedItem invisible and databind it to a single expander outside the scrollviewer that then turns visible and expands.

Comment: Thanks @T.Schwarz.  I tried the same solution you suggested and but i can't identify the end of the selected expander to close the expander.My requirement is to stick the header alone after scroll. Kindly add your suggestions if you any.

Comment: You'd just bind the IsExpanded property through a ValueConverter to the selectedItem property aswell. So on null it'd close and on anything else (re-)open. Then your Listbox items don't need to be expanders anymore. You can just make them look like a closed one. To really make it look pinned with the scrollbar on the outside is alot more finicky than anything else.

Comment: I can't move the selected item out of list as it always stay at top. I want to move the selected item to the top only when the existing list is scrolled and the selected item goes out of the current view. @T.Schwarz. Do you have any idea to find the current element is in view or out of view.